# java -jar illegal argument

Tags: java, jar

I am trying to run a jar file from windows command line like this:
`java -jar myjar.jar`
and i get the following error msg

```
-jar: illegal argument
usage: java [-options] class
```

where options include:

```
-help             print out this message
-version          print out the build version
-v -verbose       turn on verbose mode
-debug            enable remote JAVA debugging
-noasyncgc        don't allow asynchronous garbage collection
-verbosegc        print a message when garbage collection occurs
-noclassgc        disable class garbage collection
-ss<number>       set the maximum native stack size for any thread
-oss<number>      set the maximum Java stack size for any thread
-ms<number>       set the initial Java heap size
-mx<number>       set the maximum Java heap size
-classpath <directories separated by semicolons>
                  list directories in which to look for classes
-prof[:<file>]    output profiling data to .\java.prof or .\<file>
-verify           verify all classes when read in
-verifyremote     verify classes read in over the network [default]
-noverify         do not verify any class
-nojit            disable JIT compiler
```

anybody knows why that might be?

Comment: What does `java -version` return?

Comment: make sure it has a space between `java` and `-`

Comment: Java -version returns 1.1.8.24

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're using Windows Command Line, you can use javaw youJarFile.jar